# Multiple regression with autocorrelated errors

Tags: regression, time-series, autocorrelation, arma

I have a multiple regression model in R:

```
lm(formula = load ~ date + avg + I(avg^2) + I(avg^3) + weekday + 
    month + holiday, data = data, na.action = na.exclude)

Adjusted R-squared:  0.8676 
F-statistic: 4.172e+04 on 22 and 139993 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The ACF and PACF of the residuals are as follows:

[image]

[image]

Questions:

1. Can someone confirm that the error is autocorrelated?
2. If so, how to find the order of $p$, $d$ and $q$?
3. Can I use gls to build a better model?

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone confirm that the error is autocorrelated?

Clearly, there are a number of statistically significant autocorrelations and partial autocorrelations. The bars that stick out of the confidence interval (the dashed line) are statistically significant for the given significance level.

> If so, how to find the order of $p$, $d$ and $q$?

Consider your residuals to be a new time series and then refer to the methodology of identifying the orders of ARIMA model (there are plenty of threads on that here and there are also multiple online tutorials).

> Can I use gls to build a better model?

Generalized least squares (GLS) could work if your errors follow a finite-order autoregressive process (Hayashi "Econometrics", 2000, bottom of p. 416), but GLS would be inconsistent if the error is not strictly exogenous but merely predetermined (Hayashi "Econometrics", 2000, p. 58-59 and 415-416). So using GLS in your case seems a bit risky.

But you could very well try regression with ARMA errors using the function `arima` or `auto.arima` and supplying all of your regressors in the argument `xreg`. If you used `auto.arima`, you would not even have to care about the lag orders as they would be selected automatically. Of course, you should do some model diagnostics afterwards to see if the model specification is adequente in light of the data.

Comment: That GLS only works for multiple equation models is completely untrue. Most people usually encounter GLS the first time in basic econometrics courses where you have multiple regressions with heteroskedastic or autocorrelated errors.

Comment: @hejseb, maybe I was too fast. I just recited what I learned in a graduate econometrics class. I am talking about feasible GLS, of course. I know weighted least squares (WLS) is a special case of GLS which could work for a single equation model, but I am used to naming it explicitly (due to my metrics professor). In the updated answer, I give reference to Hayashi that GLS might not work under autocorrelated errors. Is there something I should learn from all this? Could GLS work here?

Comment: I can't see why it would work well for multiple equations but not for a single. Say the error is an AR(1) process. Then this can all be estimated easily and efficiently using GLS. of course the problem in practice is that you always need to assume what type of process the error follows. Is Hayashi the textbook you used? Are you sure he is saying GLS is only applicable for multiple equations? Even the Wikipedia page discusses the single equation case.

Comment: @hejseb, I took a closer look at Hayashi (p. 58-59 and 415-417) which clarified some confusion I had. Thank you for noting my mistake, which led to a refresher on GLS! By the way, in a multiple equation setting can you just use the inverse of the realized covariance matrix of the residuals for weighting? It would tell you about heterosked. across equations (assuming homosked. within equations) and autocorrelation. In a single equation setting, the matrix is singular; then you need to assume the AR order of the residuals. But no such assumption needed in the multiple equation case.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you now, but typically in systems of equations when applying GLS you will have a Kronecker structure for the covariance, so you will have something like $\Sigma^{-1}\otimes I$ instead of $\Sigma^{-1}$ as you'd have for single-equation GLS.